# Display package info of all available packages across all repos in OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I am a beginner to bash shell and I am trying to display the package info of all available packages in OpenSuse across all repos.

```
zypper info
```

needs a package as an argument. Could any command be suggested that can make this happen? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on openSUSE:

```
suse:~ # for i in `zypper se | grep -Ev "^S|---+" | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'`; do zypper info $i ; done
```

But note that this will take a really long time to finish because it literally displays the info for every available package (both installed and not installed).

Answer (score 0):

bash is not involved in this command

```
sudo zypper info -s *
```

maybe it's more helpfull to run this for only a single package, as a list of all available packages from all repositories will be quite long.

listing all available package versions across all repositories:

```
sudo zypper search -s <package>
```

HTH